# Why there isn't current in R3?

Tags: basic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVKgkF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why there isn't current in R3? Does it depends on the resistance of R3?

Comment: It is a good exercise to assume that ONE of the four resistors R has another value (for example 1.1*R) and to calculate the current through R3. Then , you can see what happens when all are equal.

Comment: And better yet, try simulating it.

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment? That's allowed but if so you should say.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its because there is no potential difference across the resistor \$R_3\$. It has nothing to do with the value of \$R_3\$.

Comment: As this seems likely to be a 'homework question' it may have been advisable to retain a degree of mystery :-). Asking them if it is may be usefuil.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon sorry about that. :-) just started answering. ll remember your advice while answering questions in future.

Answer (score 2):

The 5-resistor system is left-right symmetrical: if I exchange left and right, the current in \$R_3\$ changes its direction, but the circuit is the same (so the current remains the same, since there is only one possible value for this variable).

So it can be deduced that \$I = -I\$.